# Google Maps Change fillColor of JSON Overlay On Radio Button Selection

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

This is a basic Google Map with a JSON overlay

The **COLOR** radio button simply pulls the colors from the JSON files.

The **INCOME** radio button is a Chloropleth Map where the color or each individual polygon is based on which range the income falls in.

I want to change the fillColor of the JSON overlay for the **INCOME** Map.

I have two switches that determine the chloropleth colors

The first switch is connected to
**var incomeColorArea1**

The second switch is connected to
**var incomeColorArea2**

I also have two separate JSON files **var area1** and **var area2**

I want the first switch to be associated with **var area1** and I want the second switch to be associated with **var area2**

I tried adding a simple if then statement below:

```
    if (area1.checked) {
    var incomeColor = incomeColorArea1;
    }   else if (area2.checked) {
    var incomeColor = incomeColorArea2; 
    }
```

It does not work.

The only thing that does work is to manually change:

**incomeColor** to **incomeColorArea1** or **incomeColorArea2**

in the code below:

```
    if (color.checked) {    
        return {
          fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
          strokeWeight: 1,
          strokeColor: 'black',
          fillOpacity: 0.4,
          strokeOpacity: 1,
          zIndex: 0
        };
      } else if (income.checked) {    
        return {
            fillColor: incomeColor,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            strokeColor: 'black',
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            zIndex: 0
        };
      }
    }
```

The full code is below:

```js
   var map;
 //COLORS
 // Income Map Color
 var incomeColor1 = '#f2f0f7';
 var incomeColor2 = '#cbc9e2';
 var incomeColor3 = '#9e9ac8';
 var incomeColor4 = '#756bb1';
 var incomeColor5 = '#54278f';

 // LEGEND SCORES
 // Income Map Score
  //Area 1 incomeScore
  var incomeScore1 = 20000;
  var incomeScore2 = 50000; 
  var incomeScore3 = 80000;
  var incomeScore4 = 110000;
  var incomeScore5 = 140000;
  //Area 2 incomeScore
  var incomeScore6 = 40000;
  var incomeScore7 = 60000; 
  var incomeScore8 = 100000;
  var incomeScore9 = 160000;
  var incomeScore10 = 500000;

  function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 40.656963,lng: -112.506664},
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  var area1 = createArea('https://api.myjson.com/bins/t1mhs');
  var area2 = createArea('https://api.myjson.com/bins/zle5c');
   
function changeMap(feature) {

 var incomeScore = feature.getProperty('INCOME'); 

   var incomeColorArea1 = ""; // polygon fill color

 //Area 1 Income Switch
  switch (true) {
   case ( incomeScore == 0 || incomeScore === null ): // in case of no value
     incomeColor = '#d4d4d4'; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore1): incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor1; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore2): incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor2; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore3): incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor3; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore4): incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor4; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore5): incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor5; break;
   default: incomeColor = '#d4d4d4'; break;
  }
   var incomeColorArea2 = ""; // polygon fill color 
 //Area 2 Income Switch
  switch (true) {
   case ( incomeScore == 0 || incomeScore === null ): // in case of no value
     incomeColor = '#d4d4d4'; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore6):  incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor1; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore7):  incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor2; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore8):  incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor3; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore9):  incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor4; break;
   case ( incomeScore <=  incomeScore10): incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor5; break;
   default: incomeColor = '#d4d4d4'; break;
  }
 
  if (area1.checked) {
  var incomeColor = incomeColorArea1;
  } else if (area2.checked) {
  var incomeColor = incomeColorArea2; 
  }

  if (color.checked) { 
   return {
     fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
     strokeWeight: 1,
     strokeColor: 'black',
     fillOpacity: 0.4,
     strokeOpacity: 1,
     zIndex: 0
   };
    } else if (income.checked) {   
   return {
    fillColor: incomeColor,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    zIndex: 0
   };
    }
  }  

  // Infowindow
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    zIndex: 2
  });
  map.addListener('click', function() {
    area1.revertStyle();
    area2.revertStyle();
    infoWindow.close();
  })

  function clickFunc(event) {
    this.revertStyle();
    this.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });
  }


  function mouseFunc(event) {
    this.revertStyle();
    this.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });
  }

  function createArea(url) {
    var area = new google.maps.Data();
    
 area.loadGeoJson(url);
    area.setStyle(changeMap);
 area.addListener('click', clickFunc);  
    area.addListener('mouseover', mouseFunc);
    return area;
  }

  setArea();

  function setArea() {
    infoWindow.close();
    area1.setMap(document.getElementById('area1').checked ? map : null);
    area2.setMap(document.getElementById('area2').checked ? map : null);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area1'), 'click', setArea);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area2'), 'click', setArea);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('color'), 'click', setArea);   
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('income'), 'click', setArea);   
}
```

```css
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="content">

<form class="form"">
 <div class="switch-field">
  <input type="radio" id="area1" name="switch-two" checked/>
  <label for="area1">Area 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="area2" name="switch-two"/>
  <label for="area2">Area 2</label>
 </div>

<label class="container" style="margin-top: 12px;">COLOR
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" id="color">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
 </br>
<label class="container">INCOME
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="income">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
</form>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

`area1` and `area2` are `google.maps.Data` objects (as well as HTML Element ids), you can't access the HTML Element's 'checked' property as `area1.checked`.  Change this:

```
if (area1.checked) {
  var incomeColor = incomeColorArea1;
} else if (area2.checked) {
  var incomeColor = incomeColorArea2;   
}
```

to:

```
if (document.getElementById("area1").checked) {
  incomeColor = incomeColorArea1;
} else if (document.getElementById("area2").checked) {
  incomeColor = incomeColorArea2;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0wqgL5mu/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
//COLORS
// Income Map Color
var incomeColor1 = '#f2f0f7';
var incomeColor2 = '#cbc9e2';
var incomeColor3 = '#9e9ac8';
var incomeColor4 = '#756bb1';
var incomeColor5 = '#54278f';

// LEGEND SCORES
// Income Map Score
//Area 1 incomeScore
var incomeScore1 = 20000;
var incomeScore2 = 50000;
var incomeScore3 = 80000;
var incomeScore4 = 110000;
var incomeScore5 = 140000;
//Area 2 incomeScore
var incomeScore6 = 40000;
var incomeScore7 = 60000;
var incomeScore8 = 100000;
var incomeScore9 = 160000;
var incomeScore10 = 500000;

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: 40.656963,
      lng: -112.506664
    },
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  var area1 = createArea('https://api.myjson.com/bins/t1mhs');
  var area2 = createArea('https://api.myjson.com/bins/zle5c');

  function changeMap(feature) {
    var incomeScore = feature.getProperty('INCOME');
    var incomeColorArea1 = ""; // polygon fill color

    //Area 1 Income Switch
    switch (true) {
      case (incomeScore == 0 || incomeScore === null): // in case of no value
        incomeColorArea1 = '#d4d4d4';
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore1):
        incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor1;
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore2):
        incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor2;
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore3):
        incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor3;
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore4):
        incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor4;
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore5):
        incomeColorArea1 = incomeColor5;
        break;
      default:
        incomeColorArea1 = '#d4d4d4';
        break;
    }
    var incomeColorArea2 = ""; // polygon fill color 
    //Area 2 Income Switch
    switch (true) {
      case (incomeScore == 0 || incomeScore === null): // in case of no value
        incomeColorArea2 = '#d4d4d4';
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore6):
        incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor1;
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore7):
        incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor2;
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore8):
        incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor3;
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore9):
        incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor4;
        break;
      case (incomeScore <= incomeScore10):
        incomeColorArea2 = incomeColor5;
        break;
      default:
        incomeColorArea2 = '#d4d4d4';
        break;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("area1").checked) {
      var incomeColor = incomeColorArea1;
    } else if (document.getElementById("area2").checked) {
      var incomeColor = incomeColorArea2;
    }

    if (color.checked) {
      return {
        fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        zIndex: 0
      };
    } else if (income.checked) {
      return {
        fillColor: incomeColor,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        zIndex: 0
      };
    }
  }

  // Infowindow
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    zIndex: 2
  });
  map.addListener('click', function() {
    area1.revertStyle();
    area2.revertStyle();
    infoWindow.close();
  })

  function clickFunc(event) {
    this.revertStyle();
    this.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });
  }


  function mouseFunc(event) {
    this.revertStyle();
    this.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });
  }

  function createArea(url) {
    var area = new google.maps.Data();

    area.loadGeoJson(url);
    area.setStyle(changeMap);
    area.addListener('click', clickFunc);
    area.addListener('mouseover', mouseFunc);
    return area;
  }

  setArea();

  function setArea() {
    infoWindow.close();
    area1.setMap(document.getElementById('area1').checked ? map : null);
    area2.setMap(document.getElementById('area2').checked ? map : null);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area1'), 'click', setArea);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area2'), 'click', setArea);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('color'), 'click', setArea);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('income'), 'click', setArea);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map {
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <form class="form">
    <div class="switch-field">
      <input type="radio" id="area1" name="switch-two" checked/>
      <label for="area1">Area 1</label>
      <input type="radio" id="area2" name="switch-two" />
      <label for="area2">Area 2</label>
    </div>

    <label class="container" style="margin-top: 12px;">COLOR
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" id="color">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
    </br>
    <label class="container">INCOME
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="income">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```